# Show maximum 4 forms on user actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

**HTML**

```
    <div id="form-0">

    form 0
    </div>

    <div id="form-1" class="add-form">
    <a class="remove-form-1">X</a>
    form 1
    </div>

    <div id="form-2" class="add-form">
    <a class="remove-form-2">X</a>
    form 2
    </div>

    <div id="form-3" class="add-form">
    <a class="remove-form-3">X</a>
    form 3
    </div>

<div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"><p class="request-text">Maximum of 4 per request</p></div>
            <div class="col-sm-5"><a href="#" class="add-another-form">+ Add another form </a></div>
        </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
   counter = 0;

   function checkCounter() {
          if (counter > 4)
          {
            $('.request-text').text('You have reached maximum 4 requests ');
            $(".request-text").css("color", "green");                
            $(".add-another-form").css("box-shadow", "none");
            $('.add-another-form').unbind('click');

            return false;
          }

          counter++;
          return true;
        }





$(".add-another-form").click(function(){  


     if (checkCounter()) {
    $(".add-another-form").bind("click", function(e) {
     $(e.target).closest(".upgrade-quote-form").css("display", "block");
        });
           counter++;
        }

});
```

I would like to show the remaining 3 forms on the user actions. When they click on the add another form link, it will show form1, form2,and form3. When it reached 4 times totally, it will display, you have reached the maximum requests.

```
.add-form { display:none; }
```

I will really appreciate for a better solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to rebind the click event every time the counter counts has not exceeded its limit. Doing so will only add multiple click event into the `.add-another-form` element but is not triggered on first click. Just add a condition to prevent your incrementer, etc from being read:

```
$(".add-another-form").click(function(e){
    if ( ! checkCounter() ) {
        return;
    }

    $(e.target).closest(".upgrade-quote-form").css("display", "block");
    counter++;
});
```